# Links to old election reports expire

Tags: support, election, broken-link

When viewing the results of an old election, I'm seeing the link to OpaVote seems to have expired (or been deleted for some reason). Could a text version of the results be included in the meta post to prevent this issue?

Example: [2012 DIY Election Results](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/2012-community-moderator-election-results?rq=1) with a 
[Broken link to OpaVote](http://www.opavote.org/results/481099/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word on the street is that these reports should be persistent now, and the old ones were expiring because the person running the service didn't know we wanted to use them this way. (If this is wrong, blame Shog9.)

I think adding the text breakdown of the election to the meta posts by default would be too noisy. Especially for busy elections, it would make the posts way longer than they need to be when the point is to focus on the newly elected moderators. We provide access to the detailed voting breakdowns by providing the ballot file that could be run through OpenSTV (or probably other software so long as the settings were the same). We use Meek STV when determining election results.

That said, if you'd like to edit the old election results in where the links have expired, please go ahead.